# Is there a good React Native module for playing/streaming audios?

Tags: audio, mobile, react-native, media-player, avaudioplayer

I'm new to react native and building an audio streaming app. I found quite a few react native wrappers for native modules for playing audio files https://js.coach/react-native/react-native-ios-audio?search=audio
But none of them seem sufficient. I'm looking for a module that would

1. allow playing in the background and handle interruptions
2. have play-speed control
3. allow both streaming and local file playing

Does such a module exist? Any tips would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your intention is to use the features you mentioned in a cross-platform (android/ios) app, then you do have some options, but there isn't a single module that will cover each of those bases.

Right now, I'm using a few different modules to accomplish similar  functionality to what you're looking for:

- `react-native-audio-streaming` to stream audio from a remote URL.
- `react-native-sound` to play local audio files.
- `react-native-audio-streamer` to stream audio from a remote URL on Android, since it uses `ExoPlayer`, instead of the `AACDecoder` used by `react-native-audio-streaming`.

Support for loading sound over the network was recently added to `react-native-sound` for iOS, and someone has mentioned the possibility of implementing it on Android as well. If this happens, then it may be the best choice for your use case.

I've included the current `react-native-sound` feature set below. Hope this helps!

[image: react-native-sound features]

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm using react-native-sound right now. and will explore the streaming modules, too.

Comment: I recommend using `react-native-audio-file-streamer` which is a fork from `react-native-audio-streamer` because the maintainer is not active for a long time.

Comment: react-native-sound cannot play large audio clips. I have tried using with 4.8 MB file.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Modules.

[react-native-audio-streaming](https://github.com/tlenclos/react-native-audio-streaming)

[react-native-audio-streamer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-streamer)